# Crawling in javascript using selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a crawler in javascript that could fill the form on a link and then crawl the name of user. When I run the file in node the file gives the correct output, but when i try to run the file in firefox using php via xampp it return nothing. I am using ubuntu 17.10, node v10.10.0, geckodriver v0.21.0, npm v6.4.1 ?

```js
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var screen = {
  width: 640,
  height: 480
};

var browser = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().headless().windowSize(screen)).build();

//var browser=new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).build();
browser.get('https://webkiosk.jiit.ac.in/')

browser.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.name('MemberCode')),10000).then(function(){return browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('MemberCode'));}).then(function(temp){temp.sendKeys('17103292')}).then(function(){return browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('DATE1'));}).then(function(date){date.sendKeys(<date-of-birth>)}).then(function(){return browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('Password101117'));}).then(function(paswd){paswd.sendKeys(<password>)}).then(function(){ return browser.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/s/i/font'));}).then(function(font){return font.getText();}).then(function(captcha){browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('txtcap')).sendKeys(captcha)}).then(function(){return browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('BTNSubmit'))}).then(function(btn){return btn.click()}).then(function(ret){return browser.get('https://webkiosk.jiit.ac.in/StudentFiles/PersonalFiles/ShowAlertMessageSTUD.jsp');}).then(function(t){return browser.navigate().refresh();}).then(function(ref){return browser.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('/html/body/center/p[1]/font/b'));}).then(function(nam){return nam.getText();}).then(function(sus){return sus.substring(10,)}).then(function(sub){console.log(sub)});
```

Basically what it is doing is..
(Form to be filled) image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDoxJ.jpg)

fills the form as shown in image and the clicks submit and then..(After form filling this page loads) image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzfzE.png)

crawls the name on upper right corner "SUSHEN SHROTRIYA" and returns it.

Screenshot after running command "node .js" is [running command in terminal] image[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv4kd.png)

It runs smoothly when i run the command "node .js" but when i use a php script like

```
<?php
exec('node <file-name>.js', $x);
print_r $x;
?>
```

and run it on firefox using localhost via xampp it return nothing.

Since i am a begineer in node so i am sorry for any silly mistakes.

Comment: what does `var_dump($x)` output?

Comment: it gives the same output as before "array(0) { }"

Comment: so what do you get when you just do `node <filename>.js` in terminal or cmd

Comment: well, i have added the output as screenshot in image3.(It does exactly what it is meant to do). But in the terminal it takes quite some time while when running in firefox it gives "array(0) {}" instantly. Maybe this has to do something with the issue

Comment: you can try doing what the second example does in here http://php.net/popen using `popen()`

Comment: do i need to only specify path to js file or write command "node <file>.js" as in both cases i am getting different errors